# Почему уровень не перезагружется? теи к меня верные

Tags: unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class Reload : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (gameObject.tag=="Player")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуй вот так `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);`

Comment: Проверьте, что выполняются все условия: OnCollisionEnter будет работать при соприкосновении 2 объектов, на обоих Collider, хотя бы на 1 Rigidbody, объект на котором висит скрипт с тегом Player. Было бы здорово если вы добавили, в чем ИМЕННО ошибка, например, срабатывает ли у вас вообще это условие и ошибка в строке с LoadScene  или это условие даже не срабатывает?